# What or who is a cut out?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've googled what a cut out would be in real life relating to how it is used in the game but nothing seems to be coming up

Miller 9x out of 10 will tell you that intel on a mission has came from a cut out
Who or what is a cut out?

Following the answer from Studoku:
(Great answer just need to understand it for myself a little more)

In MGS terms what would prevent Big Boss going after the cut-out and forcing the cut-out to give information on how said cut-out got this information?

Still confused on how it can't be followed backwards, how would the information get to the cut-out in the first place

Comment: Per your edit, a cutout usually has very little value in and of themselves besides the information they hold and even then, the information could have easily be gained from a dead drop (no physical contact with the source of the info).

Comment: The cut-out is contacted by Diamond Dogs without knowing who Diamond Dogs are, or who anyone else buying the information from them is. Like at the beginning of the game, your codename was "Ahab." Miller might contact the cut-out with a codename like that, money would be transferred into an overseas account with no apparent ties to anything, and information would probably be sent via some throwaway avenue -- like a disposable email address.

Answer (score 8):

In espionage parlance, a cut-out is a mutually trusted intermediary, method or channel of communication, facilitating the exchange of information between agents. Cutouts usually only know the source and destination of the information to be transmitted, but are unaware of the identities of any other persons involved in the espionage process. Thus, a captured cutout cannot be used to identify members of an espionage cell.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-out_(espionage)